# How to fix it? CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

Tags: c, pointers

im making a pointer array to strings and this issue happened

Is there anythings wrong with my code

```
char x[50];
int num = 0;
int i = 0;
char* arrs;
printf("Enter number");
scanf("%d", &num);
arrs = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * num);
getchar();
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    printf("Enter str number %d\n" , i);
    fgets(x, 50, stdin);
    *(arrs+i) = (char)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(x));
    strcpy((arrs+ i), x);
}
```

Comment: Do not write in the memory after end of heap buffer.

Comment: *im making a pointer array to strings and this issue happened*  `char* arrs;` this is not a pointer array. It is a pointer.

Comment: Seriously, this [error would be more obvious if you **didn't** cast the return value of `malloc'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @wildplasser I tried with ** also its not working too.

Comment: Sorry but your question is unanswerable unless you explain **what the code is supposed to do when it is working correctly**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Still same error

Comment: Your crt does bounds checking?  Nice:)

Answer (score 0):

`arrs` should be a "pointer to pointer to char", rather than simply a "pointer to char":

```
char x[50];
int num = 0;
int i = 0;
char **arrs;                            // <--- pointer to pointer
printf("Enter number:");
scanf("%d", &num);
arrs = malloc(sizeof (char *) * num);   // <--- sizeof (char *)
getchar();
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    printf("Entered str number %d\n", i);
    fgets(x, 50, stdin);
    arrs[i] = malloc(strlen(x) + 1);    // <--- +1 for the terminating '\0'
    strcpy(arrs[i], x);                 // <--- arrs[i] is a char *
}

// Do something

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    free(arrs[i]);
}
free(arrs);
```

Comment: I have noticed the issue happens because the free and not because the code here but thanks too you helped me understand some stuff!
What is the proper way to free it?

Comment: @uSEwrasd Answer improved

Comment: `arrs[i] = malloc(strlen(x));` -> `arrs[i] = malloc(strlen(x) + 1);`

Comment: @sunqingyao for some reason  
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
 {
  free(friends[i]);
 } this part causes it

Comment: @uSEwrasd I cannot understand you: What's `friends[i]`? It'll be helpful if you can provide the relevant code.

Comment: @sunqingyao its a string , (its the same code you wrote here)

Comment: @uSEwrasd Can you show me the complete error message?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your are allocating memory for an array of chars not an array of String, this is char pointers. Just change `sizeof(char)` by `sizeof(char *)`